# AngularJS href is not getting dynamic value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

**javascript code:**

```
 cable.register.controller('VideoMonitorCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce','ENV', '$http', function ($scope, $sce, ENV, $http) {
        console.log('Begin in video monitor controller');

         var keepGoing =true;
        var url = '/ps/features/';
        var exists = false;
        $scope.getVideoService = function () {
        console.log("url"+$scope.hurl)
        $http.get(url,{headers: {'contentType': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}}).success( function(response) {  
        if(response!='') 
        {
            angular.forEach(response.features, function(feature){
                console.log("in for each");
                console.log(counter++)
            if(keepGoing) 
            {      
                if(feature.name.trim() === "odl-video-monitor" && feature.installed.trim() ==='x')
                {  
                    console.log('in active again');
                    $scope.color='#FFFFFF';
                    $scope.msg='Quality Network';
                    $scope.hurl='index.html#/cable/videomonitor';
                    exists=true;
                    keepGoing = false;
                }

            }
            });   
            if(!exists)
            {
                $scope.color='#BDBDBD';  
                $scope.msg='Video Quality Network is under maintenance';
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            $scope.color='#BDBDBD';  
             $scope.msg='Video Quality Network is under maintenance';
        }
        }).error(function (response) {
                 $scope.color='#BDBDBD';
                 $scope.msg='Video Quality Network is under maintenance';    
          });
         };   

     }
  ]);
```

**HTML code:**

```
<a ng-href='{{hurl}}'  ng-controller="VideoMonitorCtrl" ng-init="getVideoService()"  id="hlink" style="text-decoration:none;">    
       <div class="box" style="background-color:{{color}};">
         <div style="margin-top:15px;text-align:left;padding-left:23px;">
          <span style="font-size:24px !important;font-family:Times New Roman, serif;color:#7B7B7B;" class="Large">{{msg}}
             {{hurl}}
             </span>
         </div>
      </div>
        </a>
```

Output:

`{{hurl}}` => is printing the value in the div.

`<a href={{hurl}}`    => there is not value in hurl here and link is not enabled.

Any reason?  i am able to see the hurl content in the div but not in href?

If i write hardcoded value in href it is working but not dynamic?

Comment: The `<a>` is in scope parent of `VideoMonitorCtrl`. Move `ng-controller` to parent of `<a>`

Comment: @charlietfl Why it's worked in this plnkr? http://plnkr.co/edit/Xc9JeO3wTMSqp3DBwHgs?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the whole `<a>` element in another element and put the controller there, the scope of your VideoMonitorCtrl does not cover the `<a>` tag itself.

```
<div ng-controller="VideoMonitorCtrl" ng-init="getVideoService()">
   <a ng-href='{{hurl}}' id="hlink" style="text-decoration:none;">    
       <div class="box" style="background-color:{{color}};">
         <div style="margin-top:15px;text-align:left;padding-left:23px;">
          <span style="font-size:24px !important;font-family:Times New Roman, serif;color:#7B7B7B;" class="Large">{{msg}}
             {{hurl}}
             </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: ha ha ha.. i was trying to put the same in inner div . i did not try outer div.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: No problem :) You might want to restructure your project as well, here's a good one: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: @user2773086 Why this worked? http://plnkr.co/edit/Xc9JeO3wTMSqp3DBwHgs?p=preview